# Podman support of target build?

Tags: dockerfile, podman

DockerFile:

```
FROM scratch as stage1
RUN 1

FROM scratch as stage2
RUN 2

FROM scratch AS stage3
RUN 3
```

If I run

```
 docker  build --target stage2 .
```

stage1 will be ignored. And stage2(RUN 2) will be called

But if I run

```
podman  build --target stage2 .
```

stage1(RUN 1) will be called.

**Why is podman ignoring the target specified? Is there a way to specify the target to Podman?**

Comment: Maybe the feature request [_Skip unneeded stages from multi-stages_](https://github.com/containers/buildah/issues/2469) is related? The __buildah__ git repository contains the source code for `podman build`

Answer (score 0):

Turned out target option in podman works differently than what I expected.

This is from release 1.7 of Buildah:
The buildah bud command now accepts a --target option which **allows the build to only include the stages in the Dockerfile up to and including the specified stage.**

So everything before the specified target(stage) will be built. (I wonder the reason for this implementation!?)

Comment: Regarding your question _I wonder the reason for this implementation!?_ : The core developers of __buildah__ hang around in the [GitHub discussion forum](https://github.com/containers/buildah/discussions). Probably asking there could be a good idea.  In case you've found a bug, they could convert the discussion post in to a GitHub issue.